# CouchDB update document

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, nosql

Please confirm this is the only way I can update a document in couchDB;

In order to update a document (lets call it fooDoc) I NEED TO pass "_rev". so fisrt I need to fetch that document by following code (foo.get) and then in the callback when I have the "_rev" I can use foo.insert to update that document on the last revision:

```
var foo = nano.db.use('foo');
foo.get('fooDoc', function (err, body) {
    console.log("get:", err, body);
    foo.insert({"_id": "fooDoc", "_rev": body['_rev'], "name": "newName", "bar": "baz"}, function (err, body) {
        console.log("insert:", err, body);
    })
```

});

UPDATED:

Thanks Nuno for your help: So I was following [this documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano#db-atomic-designname-updatename-docname-body-callback); however it seems the json format for update handler is not a valid json, so I updated to the following json:

```
{
    "updates": {
        "inplace": "function(doc, req) {var field = req.form.field;var value = req.form.value;var message = 'set '+field+' to '+value;doc[field] = value;return [doc, message];}"
    }
}
```

And now when I run the following code it is not updating and the following is the log:

> error: null respose: set undefined to undefined

The code:

```
foo.atomic("update", "inplace", "bar6",
        {crazy: true}, function (error, response) {
    console.log("error:", error, "respose:", response)
});
```

I really appreciate your help in this regard

**FINAL UPDATE:**
Oh I figured out the problem; the update handler from here[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano#db-atomic-designname-updatename-docname-body-callback) is not right; the right update handler would be:

```
{
   "inplace": "function (doc, req) {var message;var body=JSON.parse(req.body);for (id in body) {doc[id] =body[id];message += 'set ', id, 'to', body[id];}return[doc,message];}"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way of updating a document without previous knowledge of the _rev number is through an [update function](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/ddocs/ddocs.html#update-functions).
In nano, update functions are called with `db.atomic`.

But you don't necessarily need to fetch the entire document, just the _rev.

As Mike said, to get the _rev of a single document you can issue a HEAD request. The _rev will be in the ETag header. In nano use `db.head`.

You can also fetch the _rev for multiple documents in one go by querying [_all_docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/api/database/bulk-api.html). In nano use `db.list`.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm using nano; I didnt see such a thing in Nano, is there any?

Comment: An update function (aka document update handler) is a server side function defined in a design document. Nano should have the ability to invoke update functions, but you need to have one.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarification; also could you please explain what designname mean in db.atomic? Based on the documentation "calls the design's update function with the specified doc in input." does it mean I need to define this update function somewhere? How and where can I define it? Sorry I'm so new to CouchDB. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Being new to Couch, can I suggest you read the [book](http://guide.couchdb.org/)? Specifically, the bit about [design docs](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/design.html). TLDR: Update functions live in the database in special documents called design documents. In nano designname is the name of your design document/function.

Comment: Oh thanks for the link; it helps alot to understand the logic; may I ask you one more quick question? It seems the update handler function which is mentioned npmjs.com/package/… is not a valid json format so I modified it to make it a valid json (Please see my updated original question) and ran the the same code which I just updated on my original question as well; but it is not updating; I really appreciate your help; I just updated my original question

Comment: outdated link for update docs

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a `HEAD` request to get the revision ID via the Etag returned in the headers. Slightly less network traffic than getting the whole document.

However, using this pattern does remove the safety-net of using the revision ID to avoid overwriting modifications to the document which have happened since you read it.